# How unarchive file with password with PHP?

Tags: php, rar

I need to unarchive *.rar file and extracte with password on PHP.
I found many decisions on PHP, but all they don't provide password in archive.
Should it do so through the exec ()?

My OS: Windows 8

Comment: @JohnConde : I disagree that it is a duplicate. First of all the related answer deals with a ZIP archive and second there are ways to extract RAR archive without using `system()` function, which may be disabled on some secure systems.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [rar_open()](http://www.php.net/manual/bg/function.rar-open.php)? It has an argument for password. I personally never used it, so can not vouch if it works well.

For Windows you need to have php_rar.dll enabled in php.ini.